# Do I need to free each individual element in a struct?

Tags: c

If I have a struct of ints, do I have to individually free all of the ints (they are not pointers), or will they be freed when I call free() on the struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they will be freed when the entire struct is freed.

(Note that you only need to `free` a struct that was allocated with `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`, not one that was allocated on a stack.)

Comment: I'd just like to add, that if you m/c/realloc it, you should free it. If not, all should be well.

Answer (score 1):

malloc and free go in pairs. 
If you did not allocate memory dynamically for it, don't free it.